# How to add a few values in one line of mysql table?

Tags: php, mysqli, registration

I'm making an online game for a mounth i guess. I made user profiles, forget password, manage your account pages. And when they enter the game they can see their names and some information abut each other. Never mind of that.

Now, i need to do items for each users. So, here is my mysql table:

user_id | name | email | password | color | items | head | face | body | hand | feet | created

But i can add just one value into items col. How can i add all the item id's the user have? Please someone help!!!

Comment: I was trying to find a way actually, but someone helped me. I understand what should i do. Thank you anyway for spending your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second table.  Remove the "items" field from this table and create a new table called Items.  In it you will have:

primaryKey | user_id | item

Then to get every item a given user has, you perform a SQL `SELECT WHERE user_id=@id` and iterate over the results.

Comment: Thank you so much! How couldn't I think that? It's so clever. :)

Comment: SQL can do some pretty complicated things.  I'm currently working on a project that has a table where the primary key is actually a composite key, consisting of the "user_id" from the main table and the "item_key" (as any given user can only have at most, one copy of the item).  Anyway, don't forget to accept and up. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a one to many relationship between the user and the number of items the user can have. You need to create another table with the following columns

user_id
item_id
item_desc

and store the item information there

Answer (score 0):

You can store the ids as serialised arrays or create an user_item table.